# Return response of REST call from method synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, rest, promise, ios9

I have created a method to execute a REST call and return the HTTP response code:

```
import Foundation

class RestUtil{

enum HTTPMethod: String{
        case GET, POST, PUT
    }

    static func sendREST(url: String, data: String, httpMethod: HTTPMethod) -> String{

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        let dataEncoded = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        request.HTTPMethod = httpMethod.rawValue
        request.HTTPBody = dataEncoded

        print("HTTPMethod: " + httpMethod.rawValue)

        var statusCode : Int = 0
        let startTime : Double = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

        func completionFunc(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?){
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
            print("statusCode: " + String(statusCode))
            print(error)
        };

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().uploadTaskWithRequest(request,
                                                                      fromData: dataEncoded!,completionHandler: completionFunc)


        task.resume()
        var currentTime : Double = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        var elapsedTime : Double = (currentTime - startTime)
        let timeOut : Double = 10

        while(statusCode == 0 && elapsedTime < timeOut){
            sleep(1);
            currentTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            elapsedTime = (currentTime - startTime)
        }

        print("Final elapsedTime: " + String(elapsedTime))

        return String(statusCode)
    }

}
```

The method executes the REST call and returns the HTTP status code from the server. The purpose of the method is to let calling methods get the return code from the REST call when it's done, without having to provide callback functions for handling the response status code, i.e. the method should be synchronous (as it is now).

It works, but feels a bit clumsy with the loop checking if the response is there yet. What is the easiest way to implement a proper [promise-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) functionality to this method (so that the return code is returned immediately when it's available), preferably without external libraries? Is this posssible e.g. using [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOperationQueue/mainQueue)?

Comment: Yes. Polling is never a good idea. The typical pattern with asynchronous calls is to supply a completion handler closure to the function, just as you do with `uploadTaskWithRequest`.  When the asynchronous network operation is complete you execute the closure to enable the caller to do whatever they need to do with the result. You can't actually return a value from the function. The is no in-built support for promises in Swift. You can use http://promisekit.org

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to achieve in your code is a synchronous rather than asynchronous use of NSURLSession. This is something that Erica Sadun has provided code for [on her blog](http://ericasadun.com/2015/11/12/more-bad-things-synchronous-nsurlsessions/). But normally you'll want to make use of a callback or preferably a delegate (NSURLSessionTaskDelegate) to monitor an upload and notify you when the task is ended so that as Paulw11 states you can then take action.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks good. I understand that in many cases there are advantages in handling the method calling chain asynchronously (for example, if there are several calls simultaneously or if the application code can proceed without waiting for the result). However, if the use case is synchronous in nature, I find that it makes the code more readable to just handle this synchronously - I have to wait for the code to execute anyway somewhere, so why I should I push callback functions around?

Comment: @Simon  you should take care because of the system resources. If you "wait" you block a thread. This thread must be _suspended_ and later be _resumed_ which is always expensive (in terms of CPU cycles). Blocking the main thread is particular bad, since you block the UI.  A user would think the app crashed. At least it becomes unusable. Use the asynchronous approach in this case, which does not block but continues just when the task is finished, and save system resources (e.g. threads, CPU cycles and battery).